# Python/SQLite3: cannot commit - no transaction is active

Tags: python, transactions, sqlite, commit

I'm trying to code a [book indexer](http://pastebin.com/YeBgbBAV) using Python (traditional, 2.7) and SQLite (3).

The code boils down to this sequence of SQL statements:

```
'select count(*) from tag_dict' ()
/* [(30,)] */
'select count(*) from file_meta' ()
/* [(63613,)] */
'begin transaction' ()
'select id from archive where name=?' ('158326-158457.zip',)
/* [(20,)] */
'select id from file where name=? and archive=?' ('158328.fb2', 20)
/* [(122707,)] */
'delete from file_meta where file=?' (122707,)
'commit transaction' ()
# error: cannot commit - no transaction is active
```

The isolation level is 'DEFERRED' ('EXCLUSIVE' is no better).

I've attempted to use connection.commit() instead of cursor.execute('commit') - nothing useful happened.

- Sure, I've searched stackoverflow and the Net, but the answers found are irrelevant.
- **Autocommit** mode is **unacceptable** for performance reason.
- I use the only database file at a time.
- My code runs in single thread.
- All the SQL execution is being done via single function that ensures that I have no more than *only one* cursor open at a time.

### So, what's wrong with transaction here?

If I use connection.commit() (note: there is no connection.begin method!), then I merely lose my data.

Sure, I've double/triple/d checked file permissions on the database file and its directory.

Comment: Nice to see a properly-asked question!

Comment: It's way too long and complicated for DB-related question. I may try to post it http://pastebin.com/YeBgbBAV

Comment: Can you please move the answer part of your question into an actual answer and mark it accepted?  Thanks.

Comment: Only tomorrow, I think - I have to wait 8 hrs to be able to do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, as it often happens I found the solution just a minutes after posing the question.

The solution was [found here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t326247-pysql-lite-transactions-question.html) and consists of the only idea:

### Never use BEGIN/COMMIT in non-autocommit mode in Python application - use db.commit() and db.rollback() only!

It sounds odd, but it works.

Comment: Well, it's **anwered** now. I'll be able to **accept** it _tomorrow_.

Comment: got something like that in `Qt` and had to use `QSqlDatabase::transaction()` instead raw-query

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty late response, but perhaps take a look at [APSW](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw) if you want finer-grain control over transactions. I ran a few tests on deferred transactions involving reads on pysqlite, and it just doesn't seem to perform correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany("insert into person(firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)", persons)
connection.commit()
```