# Cherrypy + sqlite3 + Peewee crashes when two processes execute the same code at the same time

Tags: sqlite, cherrypy, peewee

Navigating to the page `test?x=a` defined below it works.

Navigating to `test?x=a` and then quickly navigating to `test?x=b`, both the cycles will keep running for a few seconds, but one of them will eventually crash with the error `peewee.OperationalError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction`.

This is obviously not a real world test, it is a way to reproduce the real world problems that I am having once in a while.

In the real world application I see errors similar to this one when background tasks run or when the user types on a text box and many requests are quickly fired with ajax.

```
db = peewee.SqliteDatabase('db', check_same_thread=False)

class Test(peewee.Model):
    field = peewee.CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

Test.drop_table(True)
Test.create_table(True)

class MyApp:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def test(self, x):
        for i in range(1000):
            Test.create(field='%s %03d' % (x, i))
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

I already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533166/peewee-says-cannot-commit-no-transaction-is-active), but I did not have an example that would reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `check_same_thread=False` try using `threadlocals=True`.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation recommends it: http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.2/peewee/cookbook.html#multi-threaded-applications